# How can I display an address bar with a WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I've got a webview in my app. How can I display an address bar (like the one in the Browser app) show on top of it?

Comment: You can check the Browser source https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an `EditText` on top of the page.

you can set its text using `setText` to `webview.getUrl()`

Answer (score 1):

Just add an Edittext and set a key listener on that edittext for example if the user press enter key then get the url from that and load that url ... that's it ... tell me if you understand otherwise i will post the code here ..